# Fix Height and Width of The jQuery Sort-able Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've come a long way with this plugin and finally came into a solution that I was expecting as follows. Please run the below fiddle: (Better if you can copy the code in a notepad file, save in `HTML` and run it)

**How it looks in my end** 
[image: Drag and Drop]

```js
  $(function () {
            $("#sortable1, #sortable2").sortable({
                connectWith: ".connectedSortable"
            }).disableSelection();
        });
```

```css
        #sortable1, #sortable2 {
            border: 1px solid #eee;
            width: 142px;
            min-height: 20px;
            list-style-type: none;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 5px 0 0 0;
            float: left;
            margin-right: 10px;
        }

            #sortable1 li, #sortable2 li {
                margin: 0 15px 15px 15px;
                padding: 5px;
                font-size: 1.2em;
                width: 120px;
            }

            #sortable1 ul li {
                display: block;
                text-align: center;
                float: left;
            }

            #sortable2 ul li {
                display: block;
                text-align: center;
                float: left;
            }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  
  <div class="col-md-5">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <ul id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable">
                <li class="ui-state-default">Item 1</li>
            </ul>
        </div><br />
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <ul id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable">
                <li class="ui-state-default">Item 2</li>
            </ul>
        </div><br />
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <ul id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable">
                <li class="ui-state-default">Item 3</li>
            </ul>
        </div><br />
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <ul id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable">
                <li class="ui-state-default">Item 4</li>
            </ul>
        </div><br />
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <ul id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable">
                <li class="ui-state-default">Item 5</li>
            </ul>
        </div><br />
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-5">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <ul id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable">
                <li></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-12">
            <ul id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable">
                <li></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <ul id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable">
                <li></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <ul id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable">
                <li></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <ul id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable">
                <li></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The problem is, I am trying to make the boxes of the left and right panel with fixed height/width with spaces but failed miserably. I can see classes in inspect element of the browser when I use drag and drop feature of the plugin:

```
ui-sortable
ui-sortable-handle
```

I was thinking if I could override these classes and make it work accordingly as expected (Tried already but didn't get it done). I am expecting a last trial if anyone has done this before or I am just in no luck.

**Update 1**: Expected output

[image: Expected Output]

Comment: **N.B**: Contents will remain in fixed length in both the boxes.

Comment: I don't get it, you don't want the margin around the elements? This sentence is not clear `I am trying to make the boxes of the left and right panel with fixed height/width with spaces`. An image example of the desired outcome would help.

Comment: My target is, in both panels, the boxes will be in fixed size, as you can see when someone drag and drop the contents from one box to another, the boxes change its sizes as well. I just want to stop that with keeping gap between the boxes.

Comment: See my expected output @Islam Elshobokshy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a higher min-height

```
#sortable1,
#sortable2 {
    ...
    min-height: 70px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    ...
}
```

Disclaimer : This only works with your code as is and this is not responsive.

Comment: Worked @Islam Elshobokshy but can I have spaces between the boxes? Right now, the boxes are attached to each other.

Comment: @user8512043 I tested it and it works correctly. What do you mean by it doesn't work?

Comment: Worked now, let me try it again with few changes.

Comment: @user8512043 ah, I think I see, you need to put my code at the bottom of the css tags.

Answer (score 2):

Just wrap all the html element in a div.

Here a CodePen: https://codepen.io/gterigi/pen/LYNjGRK

```
<div class="FlexColumn">
...Your sortable element...
</div>

<style>
.FlexColumn{
display:flex;
}
#sortable1 li, #sortable2 li {
    min-height: 40px;
}
</style>
```

Little disclaimer. It's not responsive. If you want that all the sortable element have the same heigth always is best to attach some event listener to the element where it re-adjust the height of all the element base on the biggest one.

Comment: How does this help? The boxes' heights are still different.

Comment: Sorry, didn't get that. Got it right this time (I hope)